# Language options for GUI applications on OS X

Tags: macos

If I want to write applications that use the Mac OSX UI, is Objective-C the only choice that I have to take advantage of all the frameworks that Apple provides?

Can I use Java, which is installed with Mac OS X?

Comment: There are bindings for Python too...

Comment: +1 to nullify down vote. This is a reasonable question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Objective-C will provide the best coverage, yes, but if you want to consider portability and the possibility of getting your applications running under Windows and/or Linux, then choose [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/) and C++.

Answer (score 2):

The frameworks for native UI applications on Mac OS X (collectively known as Cocoa) are written in Objective-C so Objective-C is probably the best choice for writing your own applications, although there are bindings for Python and Ruby.

There are other toolkits that can be used (Mac OS X is a *nix system after all) but unless you are writing cross-platform apps, most people will advise you to use Objective-C and Cocoa.

Comment: What about Carbon API, which is C++, is it dead by now?

Comment: Carbon isn't supported on 64-bit. If there's one thing you learn when programming for Apple platforms is that you need to look to the future because things get deprecated aggresively.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks. I know this downside of Apple. I used to have a few iPhone applications on the market and gave them up because maintenance cost was too high compared to the income. Every new release of iOS was incompatible with the previous one.

Answer (score 1):

[MacRuby](http://www.macruby.org/), an implementation of Ruby 1.9 on top of Mac OS X Objective-C runtime and Foundation framework, is another way to go.

You still need a deep knowledge of Cocoa and a good understanding of Objective-C.

It will be provided with Mac OS X 10.7 Lion as a private framework. It already integrates very well in XCode 4 workflow, with templates for all type of application (including windowed, it goes without saying).

(MacRuby makes RubyCocoa, the Cocoa binding for Ruby, obsolete.)

Answer (score 0):

The JVM for Java under Mac OS X is no longer provided by Apple, but by Oracle ([see here](http://apple.slashdot.org/story/10/10/21/125222/Apple-Deprecates-Their-JVM)).

I guess Objective-C is the best choice for native OS X Applications. But if you want your Applications to run under other OSs (like Windows or Linux), you'll most likely use C++ and some GUI-Toolkit which supports all of them.

Comment: Thanks! Would c++ be able to consume all the framework/libs that Coca provides? And also what are the GUI-Toolkit that supports all the platforms? Qt (as what mentioned in trojanfoe's message)? what else?

Comment: I'm not sure how many Coca Frameworks are supported by C++ as i never used them. Another cross-platform GUI-Toolkit would be [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If you come from the Perl world, here is Sherm's [CamelBones](http://sourceforge.net/projects/camelbones/files/camelbones/1.1.2/) too.